# Solve for the column vector (matrices within a matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Given that the $A_{11}$ and $A_{22} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 x 3}$ are invertible, $A_{21} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 x 3}$, and $b_1, b_2, x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, then solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$ from

$\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & 0\\
A_{21} & A_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align} =$ $\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           b_{1} \\
           b_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$

What are $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $A_{11}, A_{21}, A_{22}, b_1, b_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it up into two equations

$$ \begin{aligned}
A_{11} x_1 & = b_1 \\
A_{21} x_1 + A_{22} x_2 & = b_2
\end{aligned}$$

Solve for $x_1$ and in the first equation and use it in the second

$$ \begin{aligned}
 x_1 & = A_{11}^{-1} b_1 \\
 A_{22} x_2  & = b_2 - A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} b_1 \\
\end{aligned} $$

Solve for $x_2$

$$ x_2 = A_{22}^{-1} \left(b_2 - A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} b_1 \right) $$

Re-combine the solution

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\ -A_{22}^{-1} A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} & A_{22}^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix} $$